# Node.js socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My IP address is 192.168.1.6
OS : Windows 7
Working directory  : c:\ArduinoJs
My node.js file is located in C:\ArduinoJS folder named as serialtoJSON.js listen (8080)
My index.html file is located at 
c:\ArduinoJS , the same place where node.js file is located.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://192.168.1.6:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src='https://swww.tokbox.com/v1.1/js/TB.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.pureexample.com/js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
$(function() {
        // open a connection to the serial server:
        var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.6:8080');
```

This is working fine.
But I want to keep the .js files in C:\ArduinoJS\js and load from them. 
Hence I changed the above script to

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

But this is giving 404 error.
How can I load .js files like jquery-1.8.3.js ,TB.min.js etc from my own computer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644431/default-folder-functionality-for-node-js

Comment: I am confused why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use express to serve files from a directory.
For the following example: 
create a new sub-directory where you got (your starting point) `serialtoJSON.js` named `client`

```
var express = require('express');       
var app = require('express')();     
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);    
var path = require('path');         

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client')); //Store the index and js here
http.listen(8080, function(){ console.log('[+] Server listening @ :8080');});
```